# What is the right verb to describe someone's extreme liking of something trivial?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, vocabulary

What is the right verb to describe someone's extreme liking of something trivial?

For example, someone really likes pictures of vegetables (not even sexualized pictures) and he's a super nerd of vegetable pictures, how do you describe his behavior when he starts babbling about those boring and trivial pictures?

In other words, what is the right word for this sentence "Bob ___ over his vegetable pictures again"?

Is there another word other than "[nerd-out](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nerd-out)"?

Comment: LOL  I tried and tried but I couldn't shoehorn fetish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that a one-word answer is going to be hard to find; two or more words might work, however. Here are a few possibilities:

> - "Bob is fixating on his vegetable pictures again?"
> - "Bob is fixating childishly over his vegetable pictures again?"
> - "Bob is obsessing puerilely over his vegetable pictures again?"
> - "Bob is infantilizing over his vegetable pictures again?"

With an ironic tone, an observer of Bob could say,

> - "Bob is waxing rhapsodically ad infinitum and ad nauseam over his vegetable pictures again?"
> - "Bob is lost in reverie over his vegetable pictures again?"

How about a simple insult?

> - "Bob is inanely poring over his vegetable pictures again?"
> - "Bob is admiring insipidly his vegetable pictures again?"
> - "Bob's insipidity knows no bounds when looking at his vegetable pictures."
> - "Bob is looking prosaically at his vegetable pictures again?"
> - "Bob is indulging his plebeian taste for vegetable pictures again?"

Answer (score 4):

There's the verb [**geek**<sup>1.1</sup> (or geek out)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/geek?q=+geek):

> Be or become extremely excited or enthusiastic about a subject, typically one of specialist or minority interest:
>   *I am totally geeking out over this upcoming film.*

So your sentence becomes:

> Bob's *geeking (out)* over his vegetable pictures again.

Comment: Which is basically the same as `nerd out`, I hoped there's a different word.

Comment: @kuhaku But Oxford doesn't have the verb _nerd_. Anyway, if you tell us why you're not satisfied with _nerd/geek out_, it'd be helpful.

Comment: It has a feel of a slang word or it's only a recent term, I'm looking for an older term that has a more "proper" feel to it.

Comment: @kuhaku OK. For now, what about "_Bob's [**wallowing in**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/wallow?q=wallow+in#wallow__9) his vegetable pictures again._"? Or verb phrases like '_to take excessive pleasure in_'?([here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/take-pleasure-in?q=take+pleasure)) I'll let you know if I find anything better.

Answer (score 0):

*Bob is such a **fanboy**; he is going on about his vegetable pictures again!*

> 1. an obsessive male fan, especially of something technological or from popular culture. Informal: Often Disparaging. *Apple fanboys lined up to buy the new phone.*
>
> -- [reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fanboy)

Also when looking up **fanboys** I came across a similar disparaging Japanese term **Otaku** which maybe you could use humorously?

> a Japanese term for people with obsessive interests, commonly the anime and manga fandom.
>
> -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otaku